# How do i hide my table in first time and show after user search something?

Tags: php, mysql, database, uitableview, database-design

i'm trying to build a website where users can find location of my company, but i need to hide the information at the first time and only show the location that users needed.

Here's my code:

```
    <?php
$condition  =   '';
if(isset($_REQUEST['Kota']) and $_REQUEST['Kota']!=""){
    $condition  .=  ' AND Kota LIKE "%'.$_REQUEST['Kota'].'%" ';
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['Outlet']) and $_REQUEST['Outlet']!=""){
    $condition  .=  ' AND Outlet LIKE "%'.$_REQUEST['Outlet'].'%" ';
}
if(isset($_REQUEST['Alamat']) and $_REQUEST['Alamat']!=""){
    $condition  .=  ' AND Alamat LIKE "%'.$_REQUEST['Alamat'].'%" ';
}
$userData   =   $db->getAllRecords('lokasi','*',$condition,'ORDER BY id DESC');
?>
<div>
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr class="bg-primary text-white">
                    <th>No</th>
                    <th>Cabang GO</th>
                    <th>Nama Kota</th>
                    <th>Alamat Outlet</th>
                    <th>No Telepon</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php 
                $s  =   '';
                foreach($userData as $val){
                    $s++;
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $s;?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $val['Kota'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $val['Outlet'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $val['Alamat'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $val['Nomor'];?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: why not `if( $userData = $db->getAllRecords( ... ) { // show table }`.   You should be using prepared statements though.

Comment: Passing $_REQUEST variables directly into your SQL queries like that is *ridiculously* vulnerable to attack.  Parameterize your queries!!!

Answer (score 0):

Start out with `<div style=visibility:hidden>`.  Later change it to 'visible' using JavaScript code.

Answer (score -1):

All the Code you have added is fine, you need few more things to add and it will be all working.

1. Add HTML Form with an input field for entering searching location and a submit button.

```
    <form action="" method="post">
        Search Location: <input type="text" name="location"> <input type="submit" name="submit">`enter code here`
        </form>
```

2. Add "if" Condition to check the user submitted the form and the result from the db is not empty before the table, where you are displaying all the locations.

```
   <?php if(isset($_POST['submit']) && count($userData) > 0){ ?>
   <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
               <thead>
                   <tr class="bg-primary text-white">
                       <th>No</th>
                       <th>Cabang GO</th>
                       <th>Nama Kota</th>
                       <th>Alamat Outlet</th>
                       <th>No Telepon</th>
                   </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                   <?php 
                   $s  =   '';
                   foreach($userData as $val){
                       $s++;
                   ?>
                   <tr>
                       <td><?php echo $s;?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $val['Kota'];?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $val['Outlet'];?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $val['Alamat'];?></td>
                       <td><?php echo $val['Nomor'];?></td>
                   </tr>
                   <?php } ?>
               </tbody>
           </table>
   <?php } ?>
```